# Running unit tests automatically

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-tests

In software development, we have code + unit tests. Sometimes I forget to the run unit tests, or maybe I'm too lazy to run them.

I'm looking for a tool that runs unit tests automatically when I have changed code and notifies me if I broke a test.

The tool

- must run on Windows 10
- must be compatible with MSTest
- must support .NET (C#)
- might be a plugin to Visual Studio (2015 and higher at least) or be a standalone tool

Ideally (optional)

- it will not disturb me much, i.e. performance-wise. Perhaps it can only run the tests that are affected by the code change and not all the tests all the time.
- supports other unit test frameworks such as NUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NCrunch](https://www.ncrunch.net/) is the tool of my choice.

It's a commercial tool at a price of $159 for a named user license (at the time of writing, of course).

- it works on Windows 10
- it integrates into [Visual Studio 2008 and higher](https://www.ncrunch.net/download) (i.e. is a plugin)
- it supports [MSTest, NUnit and others](https://www.ncrunch.net/support/frameworks)
- it supports [C#, VB.NET and F#](https://www.ncrunch.net/support/frameworks)

Even some optional features are fulfilled:

- it uses a [test pipeline](https://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/concepts_test-pipeline) to figure out which tests to run
- it can use [distributed processing](https://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/guides_distributed-processing) to let other PCs do the work, so you'll not notice any performance downgrade

Comment: Thomas, you might also want to set up Jenkins to build & run unit tests on a regular basis or on a version control commit (you also ought to be able to do it when a file is saved). Of course, if you already paid $159 ... But Jenkins is helpful for other stuff, like automatically performing static code analysis, checking code coverage of unit tests, checking for memory leaks, etc, etc